# HTML JQuery Ref Passed to Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

this is my code. I want the alert("SHOW ME!!") to show but it works all the way up until that point, so the line before is causing the problem. Idk how to fix it. Could it be how I'm passing reference to the function? Thank you!!!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
        </script>

    <script> 
         $(document).ready(function(){
         $("#Sub1").click(function(){
            readIngred($("#ingredForm"));
         });
     });
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function readIngred(form) {
            var checked;
            var checkedBoxes;

            //Create an array of checked radio buttons

            checked = form.elements["checkSet"];
            alert("SHOW ME!!!");
            checkedBoxes = new Array(checked.length);
            for (var i = 0, j = 0; i < radios.length; i++, j++) {

                if (checked[i].checked == true) {
                    checkedBoxes[j] = checked[i];
                } else j--;
            }

            var c = 0;
            while (checkedBoxes[c] !== null) {
                c++;
            }

            alert("You picked " + c + " ingredients");
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="ingredForm">
    <ul style="list-style-type:none;">
      <li><input type="checkbox" name="checkSet" value="Pep">Pep</li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" name="checkSet" value="Mush">Mush</li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" name="checkSet" value="Olive">Olive</li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" name="checkSet" value="Cheese">Cheese</li>
    </ul>
    <input type="submit" name="Submit_Button" id="Sub1" value="Send">
  </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Btw, the `radios` variable you put in your first for loop isn't defined. I think you meant `checked`.

Comment: Please click to accept one of the answers if they solved you problem, otherwise comment them and ask for changes.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to use pure JavaScript on a jQuery element. Change your code:

```
    <script> 
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#Sub1").click(function(){
            readIngred(document.getElementById("ingredForm"));
        });
    });
     </script>
```

See how your readIngred function passes a jQuery object as an argument, and then tries to access a pure JavaScript `form` property (`elements`) on a jQuery object? It's not legal because jQuery objects do not have an `elements` property, only form objects obtained through native JavaScript functions like getElementById or getElementByTagName or querySelectorAll have the `elements` property.

Comment: Or, better yet, forget pure JavaScript and use only jQuery methods to accomplish your task. That will make things much more cross-browser and easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead:

```
readIngred(this.form);
```

### **Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5nY6D/)**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Sub1").click(function () {
        readIngred(this.form);
    });
});
```